# Is there an easy reliable way to transfer a file over local network using Electron / Node.js / terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Are there any built-in methods in Electron / Node.js allowing to transfer a file over local network to another device?

I want to be able to send files **locally** from one computer to another (through an Electron app), but I also want it to be able to send files to smartphones.

How do I do it? Is it possible to just create a temp local server and download the file from another device by opening the URL (e.g. `192.168.0.x:x/file.txt`)?

I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick-transfer which does exactly that, but for some reason opening the link on another device doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As painful as it is for me to suggest... I'd recommend WebRTC for this, for these reasons:

- It will make a local connection, when possible.
- It will work over the internet as well, if required.
- You can work around any firewall difficulties with TURN.
- You will have compatibility with browsers.
- You won't be opening up some server to a file that anyone on the network can get... transmission occurs over a secured connection.  (This doesn't mean you can ignore other security aspects in your application however!)

Sample code:  https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/

*Commentary: It's amusing to me that in 2018, we still haven't solved the problem of sending a file from point A to point B.  Network Neighborhood in Windows was the golden age, and now it's all screwed up with this newfangled cloud crap.  :-)  Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/949/*

[image: XKCD]

Comment: Yeah, that's frustrating. Why there's still no open-source cross-platform tool on JS for performing simple **local** file transfers. Do you have any thoughts on why that generated link mentioned in the question doesn't work? I opened that generated `192.168.0.106:6272/test.txt` URL from another device connected to the same network and it didn't download the file? Is this a problem with my router?

Comment: Local firewall on the host, probably.  Nothing to do with your router unless you're crossing into another network.

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction. The firewall indeed was blocking node.js. I disabled the firewall rules and it worked.